# What mistake is made when words are incorrectly split into two different words, changing the meaning?

Tags: word-usage, category, split

Is there a terminology for when correct English words that are made up of other English words are incorrectly split to use the shorter words out of context?

Examples of the error I am trying to categorise:

- Today I'll wear my everyday shoes. vs. Today I'll wear my every day shoes.
- The weathermen have forecast rain. vs. The weather men have forecast rain.
- An ideal setup would be full waterproofs. vs. An ideal set up would be full water proofs.
- That would give me a headache. vs. That would give me a head ache.
- We won thanks to great teamwork. vs. We won thanks to great team work.
- Always make sure you backup your computer. vs. Always make sure you back up your computer.

Comment: I don't understand your question. In none of the examples does the wrong choice inadvertently mean something else. What you're describing are merely spelling errors.

Comment: `Always make sure you back up your computer's DATA`.is the right choice. `Backup` doesn't apply here

Comment: Your last example (using *backup* as a verb) is actually wrong. The verb is *back up*, and the noun is *backup*. Otherwise, you would have to say *"I'm backupping my computer daily"*.

Comment: Technically it's known as a "mistake".

Comment: I'm not sure these are even mistakes: many, if not all, are just alternatives or older forms.

Comment: Psycho The Rapist. Psychotherapist.

Comment: "Examples of the error I am trying to categorise:" - Spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake of splitting a word incorrectly into two different words is quite simply—wait for it—a ***misspelling***. I can think of no sub-class of this error for when a change in meaning is caused.